# Run a Shell Script from the Directory it is in

Tags: bash, shell

I am relatively new to shell scripts. I am trying to create a script that can initiate grunt.js by launching the script in Finder (Mac). I want to be able to place this script anywhere and for it to just work by running the version of grunt in the folder the script is located.

How can I achieve this? I have looked for a few hours trying to find a solution but due to my lack of knowledge I am struggling.

Does anyone have a snippet that can CD to the directory the script is stored and run a command?

Comment: You may find [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in) useful.

Comment: I did look at this, but I could not work out how to CD to that directory. I tried all the snippets but when I tried 'ls' it still showed me the files in the user directory.

Comment: If you call `cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )"` then from that point on the current directory will be the one that the script is stored in.

Comment: Thanks! Its working now :) I don't really have knowledge with shell scripts and this is what I needed.

Comment: Use my solution here: https://github.com/lingtalfi/printScriptDir/blob/master/printScriptDir.sh  It handles symlinks, relative paths and absolute paths. Tested on linux and macOsX

Answer (score 0):

If you call [`cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )"`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html) then from that point on the current directory will be the one that the script is stored in.